# creating a javaRDD using newAPIHadoopFile and FixedLengthInputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to create a Spark javaRDD using the newAPIHadoopFile and the FixedLengthInputFormat. Here is my code snippit,

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setInt(FixedLengthInputFormat.FIXED_RECORD_LENGTH, JPEG_INDEX_SIZE);
config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
String fileFilter = config.get("fs.defaultFS") + "/A/B/C/*.idx";
JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, BytesWritable> inputRDD = sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(fileFilter, FixedLengthInputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, BytesWritable.class, config);
```

At this point I get the following exception:

```
Error executing mapreduce job: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am new to Spark. David